# $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\left( \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{n\cdot \frac 1 {2n}}-1\right)}{\frac 1{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}.$ Then we have$$a_n=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \to 0.$$

Now
$$\begin{align}
 a_n&=\sqrt{n} \left(\sqrt{1+\frac 1 n}-1\right)\\~\\
&=\sqrt{n} \left( \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{n\cdot \frac 1 {2n}}-1\right)\\~\\
&=\frac {n^{\frac 1 2}}{2n}\cdot \frac{\left( \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{n\cdot \frac 1 {2n}}-1\right)}{\frac 1{2n}}\\~\\
\end{align}$$

Now my question is using $$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{x}-1}{x}=1$$ And **sequential criterion** for limit of function can we conclude that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}  \frac{\left( \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{n\cdot \frac 1 {2n}}-1\right)}{\frac 1{2n}}=1$$

If yes than how can we justify that step, as there are two sequences in that term.

Comment: $\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{ \frac 1 {2}}=1+\frac{1}{2n}+o(\frac1n)$

Comment: If $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for $x>0$, $f'(1)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(1+h)-1}{h}$

Comment: @Mittens Can you explain how it answer my question?

Comment: @MeetPatel: take $h=\frac{1}{n}$ and see what you get.

Comment: @Mittens Please check edit once.